# openssl-1.0.0o: undefined symbol: FIPS_mode

Tags: openssl, redhat, undefined-symbol, fips

I am trying to use `openssl-1.0.0o` (I need to use `1.0.0` line, with fix to openssl POODLE attack: https://www.openssl.org/~bodo/ssl-poodle.pdf, https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20141015.txt).

I have built `openssl-1.0.0o` RPMs but after installing it I am experiencing the following issue when trying to use `ssh`/`scp` from this host:

```
ssh: symbol lookup error: ssh: undefined symbol: FIPS_mode
```

Have I missed something? I do not see such issue with `openssl-1.0.0j`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to use openssl-1.0.0o ... 
>   ...
>   ssh: symbol lookup error: ssh: undefined symbol: FIPS_mode

OpenSSL 1.0.0's cryptography was never FIPS validated, so that version of the library is not FIPS capable (the second follows from the first). You need to move OpenSSL 1.0.1, or you need to engage the OpenSSL Foundation to get a private label validation for 1.0.0.

Or, you could "fake it" by providing the missing exports *if* you don't need FIPS validation. That will include `FIPS_mode_set`, `FIPS_mode` and friends. You can get a partial list of the potential `FIPS_*` functions in *Appendix I - API Entry Points by Source File* from the [OpenSSL User Guide 2.0 for the FIPS Object Module](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf).

Related: [OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/OpenSSL-1-0-0-fips-29-Mar-2010-td54706.html) on the OpenSSL mailing list.

---

> Have I missed something? I do not see such issue with openssl-1.0.0j.

Hmmm... I thought Red Hat used NSS for its validated cryptography. There's no telling what Red Hat is doing.

<strike>And are you sure that not openssl-1.0.1j? According to [ftp.openssl.org/source/](ftp://ftp.openssl.org/source/), there is no openssl-1.0.0j</strike>

Comment: Thank you for detailed response. I will try with openssl 1.0.1. Yes, the previous version was is 1.0.0j - ftp://ftp.openssl.org/source/old/1.0.0/openssl-1.0.0j.tar.gz.

Comment: No problem. The previous version I got is: 1.0.0j-fips - it looks that it was patched by RedHat folks. I will try to patch 1.0.0o as well.

Comment: @@Marcin - I seem to recall something about that (distant memory). It sounds like Red Hat got the validation for OpenSSL. But they did not share it with the world, and they kept it to themselves. (If they shared it, the platform would have been listed under OpenSSL's 1747 certificate (IIRC)).

Comment: I have built openssl-1.0.1j with openssl-fips-2.0.9 (per your advice), then new openssh stack (6.7p1) for SSL version match with valid headers. And it works! Thank you for support.